# Executing a shell command and getting colored output in C++

Tags: c++, pipe, terminal-emulator

I am looking for a way to execute a terminal command and get the colored output of it. In that below post, they discuss how to get the output of an executed command which is partially what I need.

But the thing is terminal will not output with ANSI color codes, which as I understand it, programs know if they output to the terminal or not so they give a colored output when printing to the terminal and non-colored for else. Even though some commands support forced-colored outputs (like `grep --color=auto`, `ls --color`) not all of them do.

I also tried the command `script` which is said it saves colors but did not work for me.

[How do I execute a command and get the output of the command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po)

Comment: So you want to know which ANSI color codes were used in a command like `ls --color` ?

Comment: Most commands don't output colours if they detect they aren't running in a tty terminal, you'll have to fool it into thinking it is somehow

Comment: `unbuffer` sounds promising https://superuser.com/a/751809

Comment: Thank you for your research, @AlanBirtles. The command `unbuffer` is not something that comes by default. My primary goal was to achieve this by using system libraries, still thanks.

Comment: Yes, @AndreasDM. I am trying to get executed command output with ANSI color codes as some commands do that with `--color` option.